# Discovering Undersea Life during a Long Journey

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a story which I read in the 2010s - it felt fairly recent, probably that decade. It may have been one of the Clarkesworld stories.

It starts off in an underwater station on a mostly unpopulated water planet. There are only hints at most of any life on the planet but it is described beautifully. A man and woman are setting off on a long journey through various underwater canyons over an uncertain route.  They quickly get in over their heads and see some things suggesting more is going on than they realized... Not exactly intelligence but some kind of spirit or jellyfish, leading them back to the base. The story of their voyage goes on for a long time and in the end they make it back, charged with respect and wonder for the path they were led on, but still uncertain if the life was real or not.